# Meaning of "Calls Access Too Much Data" in Facebook App Diagnostics

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, throttling, facebook-insights

On our Facebook Application's Diagnostics page, there is a message saying that for two different queries, our "Calls Access Too Much Data". Does anyone know exactly what this means?

Specifically, does this mean that our average request size per call is too large, or that we are accessing too much data in aggregate? We make great effort to batch queries together as much as possible (both for GraphAPI and FQL queries), so that we can limit our total number of queries per user. However, if these two calls are really "accessing too much data", does that mean that we should be less agressive about batching these queries?

Comment: How many queries are you including in every batch?

Comment: up to 75 queries per FQL multiquery, up to 20 graph api calls per batch request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like some of your queries are trying to pull too much information in a single call. If you can try to break it down into smaller batches, you should see these errors decrease.

I'll look into getting the documentation around the limits made a little clearer.

Comment: Thanks! we will go ahead and do that.